# Tell when Bluetooth module connects on Arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm working on a project with Android and Arduino and am trying to figure out how on the Arduino side to tell if the Bluetooth is connected or not.

I'm using one of these [Bluetooth Modules](http://www.ebay.com/itm/290859124600?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) to connect. I know I can send a command through Android, but I'm trying to have an action happen automatically when they connect and not have to run a background application on the Android if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the module supplied and *nothing else* you cannot: notice the module has four connectors:

- Power (Vcc)
- Ground
- Tx (send)
- Rx (receive)

Given this interface the only way to determine whether the bluetooth module is paired is to send something to the paired device and have it respond in such as way that your Arduino knows that it is connected. For instance, if your Android program always responds with `"Hi there!"` when it receives a string `"Hello?"`, then by seingin `"Hello?"` your Arduino will know that it is paired with your Android phone/tablet. Your Arduino could poll (send the interrogation string) every minute (or every five seconds) to see if it is paired with your device.

---

There is a better way, but it will require some soldering on your part.  If your module is HC-03/HC-05-based, then the PIO9 pin is the "paired indicator LED" (see datasheet [here](http://elecfreaks.com/store/download/datasheet/Bluetooth/HC-0305%20serail%20module%20AT%20commamd%20set%20201104%20revised.pdf)). You could connect that pin to an Arduino input pin and read the level: reading digital `1` will indicate that the device is paired, while reading digital `0` will indicate that it is not. It is possible, though not certain, that the pin on your module labeled `STATE` is exactly this kind of a pin, i.e. it indicates the paired status. Unfortunately. this pin it isn't connected to the header, so you'll have to solder a wire to the correctponding pad to connect it to your Arduino.  You should test it first by connecting a multimeter in voltage mode to that pad and measure the potential between that pad and ground in paired and non-paired state. If this is the pin that responds to the paired state then you are golden. It might be that it indicates power (like the HC-03/05 `PIO8` whilc blinks when on). If it turns out that the `STATE` pin is not the pairing status, then you should request a datasheet from your supplier, and use that to find the status LED connection: one is likely to exist. Once you found the correct pad, verify its function using the voltmeter again. Then solder a wire to that connection and read it from your Arduino.

**IMPORTANT**: Make sure that your Arduino *never* puts out a digital `1` on the Arduino pin connected to the bluetooth module status pin: these bluetooth modules run on 3.3V, and connecting any unprotected pins to 5V will be damaging. The Vcc and Txd pins are voltage shifted in the module you bought, but the LED/Status lines are likely not to be. So if the Arduino pin connected to "status" on your Bluetooth module is configured as output and you `digitalWrite(HIGH)` to it, you will likely damage the Bluetooth module.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that is what I was trying before and even with the data sheet all the pins match up but nothing gets outputted for the PIO9 pin.  I think the module I have is a HC-04/HC-06.  You wouldnt know where to get a HC-05 would you?

Comment: I think most of the cheapest ones sold on Ebay are those, and also [this one](http://dx.com/p/wireless-bluetooth-rs232-ttl-transceiver-module-80711) from DX, however they are sold without the 5->3.3 voltage shifters so you'd have to provide that.  Also maybe search for HC-04/HC-06 datasheet, see what you can find?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntaely, the `HC-05` will switch states when paired, but won't output a 1 until it's actually connected to something.

For instance, I can unpair my phone from the `HC-05`, pair again, and then the LED will change state, but the output of the STATE pin is still 0. If I open up an app, and connect to the device manually then the LED, and STATE pin will change state. The LED will periodically blink twice, and the STATE pin outputs a 1 to the Arduino.

If you would like to read the the value of the STATE pin, connect a wire to any of the inputs to the arduino, and code `Serial.println(digitalRead(inputPin));` `inputPin` being the wire to the input of the Arduino.

I've been fighting this thing for months, and have yet to find a way to make this thing automatically connect to my phone. It won't even allow for me to connect to it from my phone to the `HC-05` unless I download an app onto my Android. It's possible to bind the `HC-05` to a certain address, but even this did not work for me. I want to mess with the `"AT+CLASS"` command, but the documentation behind the instruction has hindered me thus far.

Answer (score 0):

From the HC-05 datasheet we see that the connection status depends on the output from PI09. Apparently sending "AT+BIND?" to the module will return the status of PI08 & PI09 in the form,
"+ POLAR=PI08,PI09" however this makes no sense to me because in order to get this you must enter AT mode and entering AT mode will disrupt the paired connection, hence it will always send PI09 marked as "not connected".

THUS in order to see if the connection is still live from the arduinos POV I can only see 2 feasible ways:

- Program arduino to, every so often, send a "hello?" and if it doesn't receive the expected "Hi back" response, then it is to assume that it isn't connected.
- Connect PI09 to an arduino input pin and read it's value whenever you want to check if the connection is live or not

Answer (score 0):

`AT+STATE?` will return the current state of the connection. Yes you will need to enter at mode, that is done by bringing up pin 11 HIGH on the HC05 module. It does require soldering but it's kinda worth it. It then allows full AT control of the device, then set it LOW to return it to normal working mode.

Another option, which I don't fully understand, is the `AT+MPIO?` command, which returns the state of all the pins in some strange masked format I don't understand yet.

I use the first option above so that I can terminal (Bluetooth) from my phone to the HC05 and switch on a led/relay etc (ie bring up pin 2 to HIGH) on the HC05. This required entering AT mode (pin 11 HIGH), sending the command `AT+PIO=2,1` and then setting pin 11 to LOW to return to normal working mode.

Note: I noticed I had to put a 200ms delay in between high and AT and LOW commands. Angela's solution is nice - I use a cheap XBEE Bluetooth module ([HC-05 Bluetooth Bee Master & Slave Module with Bluetooth XBee for Arduino uk2015](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/182073486729?)) 2 units(HC05/6) for 5Stg which are laid out in XBEE format - handy for the 3.3v.