# how to use arduino bluetooth HC-6 's state pin and tell it paired or not

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am using a Bluetooth HC-6 in my project and I need to **tell whether it's paired or not**.
I know there is some way like : look the led on the sensor.
led blinking => not pair
led not blinking => is paired
so I want to know how to get the led signal as an input
[Tell when Bluetooth module connects on Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005454/tell-when-bluetooth-module-connects-on-arduino/16020652#16020652) 
This article is about HC-5 and I wonder **how to use state pin on HC-6**.
I also have searching about the pin **state** on the **HC-6** ,but i just get few information :(
By the way, I know that the `BTSerial.available()` can know whether **the message was sent** or not , but
**does the Bluetooth sensor have any function or method to tell the device paired or not?**
Thank you for your reading. :D